# Read video stream from raspberry pi using openCV

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I'm trying to build a robot which has efficient low latency video stream. I was able to capture the video using the raspberry pi camera and view it on VLC Media Player using this code:

server (my pc):

```python
import socket
import subprocess

# Start a socket listening for connections on 0.0.0.0:8000 (0.0.0.0 means
# all interfaces)
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8000))
server_socket.listen(0)

# Accept a single connection and make a file-like object out of it
connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('rb')
try:
    # Run a viewer with an appropriate command line. Uncomment the mplayer
    # version if you would prefer to use mplayer instead of VLC
    cmdline = ['vlc', '--demux', 'h264', '-']
    #cmdline = ['mplayer', '-fps', '25', '-cache', '1024', '-']
    player = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        # Repeatedly read 1k of data from the connection and write it to
        # the media player's stdin
        data = connection.read(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        player.stdin.write(data)
finally:
    connection.close()
    server_socket.close()
    player.terminate()
```

client (robot):

```python
import socket
import time
import picamera

# Connect a client socket to my_server:8000 (change my_server to the
# hostname of your server)
client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(('my_server', 8000))

# Make a file-like object out of the connection
connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')
try:
    camera = picamera.PiCamera()
    camera.resolution = (640, 480)
    camera.framerate = 24
    # Start a preview and let the camera warm up for 2 seconds
    camera.start_preview()
    time.sleep(2)
    # Start recording, sending the output to the connection for 60
    # seconds, then stop
    camera.start_recording(connection, format='h264')
    camera.wait_recording(60)
    camera.stop_recording()
finally:
    connection.close()
    client_socket.close()
```

Now I want to read the frames using opencv instead of VLC. Is there a way to do this?

Most answers I have seen involves running the raspi as a rtsp server and then accessing it with cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://IPaddress:Port'). I want the raspi to be the client though.

Update: actually it'd be even better if there is a way to play the stream directly on a PyQt GUI. Essentially I'd like to make my own version of VLC...

Comment: not an OpenCV problem. OpenCV can use ffmpeg and/or gstreamer as video backends. prototype the situation using just ffmpeg/gstreamer. when that works, you can see about hooking it up with OpenCV.

Comment: I have updated my question. I have looked into QMediaPlayer but that still relies on the pi being the rtsp server.

Comment: So you're just using VLC to show camera frames?

Comment: Currently yes, but as I said I want to show frames on my own UI.

Comment: I have looked into ffmpeg streaming but virtually all approach the problem with running a rtsp server on the Pi. Has anyone got an example that displays the video streamed by the raspi code above?

Comment: Have you tried OpenCV [imshow](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563) ?